# Excel: Formula to search in a cell of a table if any of a list of values is contained in the cell, summing 1 per each found value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to work in a formula that can search a set of values in a specific cell, and if so, sum 1 per each found value.
Today I am able to achieve it partially with the following formula:

```
=OR(COUNTIF([@[Aux March RC Prio]];"*"&RegionTopPrio[Region Top Prio]&"*"))
```

Where

- [@[Aux March RC Prio]] is the cell in the table I am searching.
- RegionTopPrio[Region Top Prio] is a table containing a list of values to be searched in the cell

but I can only get TRUE or FALSE when at least one value is found, so I can not know how many values were found.

Data Examples

**Main Table:**

| ID | Aux March RC Prio | Formula Result | Expected Result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | EMEA#1;LATAM#8; | TRUE | 2 |
| 2 | EMEA#20;US#3; | TRUE | 1 |

**RegionTopPrio table**

| Region Top Prio |
| --- |
| #1; |
| #2; |
| #3; |
| #4; |
| #5; |
| #6; |
| #7; |
| #8; |

Is there any possibility to achieve the above?
Many thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried something like this : `=COUNT(SEARCH(RegionTopPrio[Region Top Prio];[@[Aux March RC Prio]]))`

Comment: Or even your formula should work, remove the `OR()` and wrap within `SUM()` / `SUMPRODUCT()` --> `SUM(COUNTIF([@[Aux March RC Prio]];"*"&RegionTopPrio[Region Top Prio]&"*"))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try one of the followings:

[image]

---

```
=COUNT(SEARCH(RegionTopPrio,[@[Aux March RC Prio]]))
```

---

Or,

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS([@[Aux March RC Prio]],"*"&RegionTopPrio[Region Top Prio]&"*"))
```

---

**EDIT: - 12/3/2023**

As OP mentioned in comments:

> *Many thanks Mayukh!, it works great. Only problem I have with this*
> *approach is that if there are 2 same prios given in the same cell,*
> *only 1 will be counted, for example, when having EMEA#1;LATAM#1,*
> *expected result should be 2 and now we will have 1*

---

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>F2</kbd>

```
=COUNT(SEARCH(RegionTopPrio[Region Top Prio],TEXTSPLIT([@[Aux March RC Prio]],";",,1)&";"))
```

---

Or,

• Formula used in cell <kbd>G2</kbd>

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(RegionTopPrio[Region Top Prio],"#"&TEXTSPLIT([@[Aux March RC Prio]],{"#",";"},,1)&";"))
```

---

Comment: Many thanks Mayukh!, it works great. Only problem I have with this approach is that if there are 2 same prios given in the same cell, only 1 will be counted, for example, when having EMEA#1;LATAM#1, expected result should be 2 and now we will have 1

Comment: @JoseHueso then use this formula: `=COUNT(SEARCH(RegionTopPrio[Region Top Prio],TEXTSPLIT([@[Aux March RC Prio]],";",,1)&";"))` or `=SUM(COUNTIFS(RegionTopPrio[Region Top Prio],"#"&TEXTSPLIT(Table8[@[Aux March RC Prio]],{"#",";"},,1)&";"))`

Comment: that works like a charm. Many thanks for the help

Comment: Pleased and glad to know that @JoseHueso =)